# I just want the last 3 characters of a column returned to the original file

Tags: csv, awk, sed

first 2lines of my data:

```
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
"2015-10-06","123427","456060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"
```

I only want the last 3 characters of column 2 and column 3, I dont want the column header affected. 
happy for a solution that can do column2 first and then do column 3

I am fiddling with sed and awk at the minute but have no joy yet.

this is what I want:

```
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
"2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"
```

**edit1** this gives me the last 3 digits(+ "), just need to write this back to the orig file?

```
$ awk -F"," 'NR>1{ print $2}' head_test_real.csv | sed 's/.*\(....\)/\1/'
427"
592"
007"
592"
409"
742"
387"
731"
556"
```

**edit2** this works but i lose the double quotes "123427" goes to 427, i ould like to keep the double quotes. 
 * NR>1 works on the rows after the 1st row.

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{$2=substr($2,length($2)-3,3)}1' OFS=, head_test_real.csv
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
"2015-10-06",427,"456060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"
```

**edit3** @Mark tks fro correct answer, and here just for my ref on the quotes.

```
$ ####csv.QUOTE_ALL

$ cat out.csv
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
"2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"



$ ####csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL

$ cat out.csv
Rec_Open_Date,MSISDN,IMEI,Data_Volume_Bytes,Device_Manufacturer,Device_Model,Product_Description
2015-10-06,427,060,137765,Samsung Korea,Samsung SM-G900I,$39 Plan

$ ###csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC

$ cat out.csv
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
"2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"



$ ###csv.QUOTE_NONE

$ cat out.csv
Rec_Open_Date,MSISDN,IMEI,Data_Volume_Bytes,Device_Manufacturer,Device_Model,Product_Description
2015-10-06,427,060,137765,Samsung Korea,Samsung SM-G900I,$39 Plan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""} NR>1{for (i=2;i<=3;i++) $i=substr($i,length($i)-2)} 1' file
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
"2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"
```

As with any command, to write back to the original file is just:

```
command file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: So the pattern holds: I post an answer claiming `awk` is not ideal for the problem, and @EdMorton posts an elegant answer using `awk`.  I clearly need to stop saying that.

Answer (score 2):

While `awk` seems like a natural fit for comma-separated data, it doesn't deal well with the quoted-fields version. I would recommend using a dedicated CSV-processing library like the one that ships with Python (both [2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)):

```
import csv
with open('in.csv','r') as infile:
  reader = csv.reader(infile)
  with open('out.csv','w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(next(reader)) 

    for row in reader:
      row[1] = row[1][-3:]
      row[2] = row[2][-3:]
      writer.writerow(row)
```

Put the above code into a file named e.g. `fixcsv.py` and make the filenames match what you have and want, then just run it with `python fixcsv.py` (or `python3 fixcsv.py`).

I set it to quote everything in the output (`QUOTE_ALL`); if you don't want it to do that, you can set it to `QUOTE_MINIMAL`, `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` or `QUOTE_NONE`.

The `row` assignments replace the second and third fields (`row[1]` and `row[2]`, since the first field is `row[0]`) with their last three characters (`[-3:]`).  You could also do it arithmetically with e.g. `row[1] = int(row[1]) % 1000`.

Comment: ++; works well in Python 2.x; what's needed to make it work in 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/",".*?(...",")/","$1/ if $. > 1' < input > output
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints the result
- `s/regex/replacement/` is a substitution
- `.*?` matches anything (like `.*`), but the question mark makes it "frugal", i.e. it matches the shortest string possible
- `(...",")` creates a capture group starting three characters before `","`, it can be referenced as `$1`.
- `$.` is the line number, no replacement happens on line 1.

Make sure the first two columns are always quoted and the second column is never shorter than 3 characters.

To modify the third column, you can modify the regex to

```
perl -pe 's/^("(?:.*?","){2}).*?(...",")/$1$2/ if $. > 1'
#                         ~
```

Modify the indicated number to handle any column you like.

Comment: @HattrickNZ: You count the `","` in the regex. The first one matches the boundary between col1 and col2, the second one col2-col3. Therefore, what it captures is the trailing part of col2.

Comment: tks  got that, what I was trying to work out was how to adjust it so it it would work on col3, seperately or at the same time? Currently it only  changes the value in col2. <br>`$ perl -pe 's/",".*?(...",")/","$1/ if $. > 1' < in.csv
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
"2015-10-06","427","456060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"
`

Comment: regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/wH4yH1/1) this is the best i can [do](https://regex101.com/r/wH4yH1/2) can't capture last 3 digits of 3rd col.

Comment: tks, next q is how to do 2 cols at the same time something like `{1|2}` but it is okay as is. tks